# Make the image to be a link only and not outside in relation to overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make the image only to be a link only and not outside of the picture with support of overlay functionality. I have problem to make the picture to make as a link only in relation to overlay. Today, the layout is perfect but not the link.

```css
#aaa {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 128px;
  height: 845px;
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-drink-3/512/Candy-128.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
#aaa:hover {
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-drink-3/512/Candy-128.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="aaa"></a>
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do. You code example doesn't seem to make an sense. Why are you using fixed positioning? Why have you set the height of the link to 845px - significantly larger than the image you're using.

Comment: THe goal is tot make the button to be a link, not outside of the picture. THe picture shall also be in the left middle of the webpage. Please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: What button? There isn't one in the example.

Comment: The candy picture is the button

Comment: Ok, so you want to have a picture as a link, which is positioned halfway down the page, over the top of all other content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more responsive solution would be to use flexbox layout:

```css
.overlay {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
#aaa {
  display: block;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-drink-3/512/Candy-128.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
#aaa:hover {
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-drink-3/512/Candy-128.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <a href="" id="aaa"></a>
</div>
```

You can also align this centrally, like in the followin example:

http://codepen.io/jaycrisp/pen/ZQMEBm

Comment: I have a another quesion, is it possible to have the picture in the bottom with 20 px distance away from the bottom? Thanks!

Comment: yes, have a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a good guide on flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the height of the link to same height as the image - 128px. Then display inline-block so the link state is exactly as you have specified. To get the link to be in the middle of the page you want it to be 50% from the top of the page minus half the height as a margin.

```css
#aaa {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
margin-top:-64px;
top:50%;
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-drink-3/512/Candy-128.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
#aaa:hover {
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-drink-3/512/Candy-128.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="aaa"></a>
```